# Where to find dependency has org.springframework.scripting.Messager?

Tags: java, spring, maven, dependencies, maven-3

I am reading *Spring Framework reference documentation* (version 5.0.0.M1), [page 70](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-extension-bpp-examples-hw):

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.scripting.Messenger;

public final class Boot {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("scripting/beans.xml");
        Messenger messenger = (Messenger) ctx.getBean("messenger");
        System.out.println(messenger);
    }

}
```

I try adding:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

[image]

but cannot resolve dependency. Where to find dependency has `org.springframework.scripting.Messager`?

Comment: did u try Maven -> Update project :/

Comment: It is a sample... That isn't a spring framework class... It is a sample with a groovy bean, defined a a .groovy file.